# How to pass any user specific attribute (sub/email) in a "Universal Navigation link" in google-apps-marketplace?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I have a google-marketplace-applciation (uses Oauth2) which allows google users to login to an external application via Google-SSO. This is currently setup by specifying an authentication REST endpoint of the external application in the "Universal Navigation link" section in the marketplace app.

My requirement is to capture any user specific attribute during the above request from marketplace-app to external-application. As per the documentation it seems "${DOMAIN_NAME}" is the only supported parameter in "Universal Navigation link". Apart from this is there any other auto populated parameter which can be used to uniquely identify the user (i.e. sub-Id, email) ?